# iPhone Wi-Fi disconnecting when I watch YouTube

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 4S which works perfectly fine in all aspects… except one. Whenever I'm watching a video on YouTube, especially one with movement (not so much on videos that show one background with a song playing), the Wi-Fi connection completely cuts out. I have to manually go to settings and reconnect. This can happen multiple times per video. I've watched videos on other sites and they didn't appear to have this problem, although it's worth noting that none of them use the same player as YouTube. This has happened ever since I got the phone and has really been annoying me. How do I stop this?
Additional information: I always run the most recent update to IOS, so I'm currently on 9.3.

Answer (score 1):

Try to troubleshoot, it sounds like you have some problems, which are not related to the application itself.

Some ideas to check:

- check the WiFi signal, how many bars do you see in the place where you normally watch it, it could be you covering the signal with someting (phone stand, hands, walls, furniture, etc), and signal goes weaker, until totally lost;
- try to connect to another WiFi access point, with the same video application or even the same video clip, and check if you experiencing the same issues;
- check the settings on your WiFi router (or data plan limitations with your provider), may be it has some bandwidth limitation, and when you watch videos which are heavy on traffic - it just cuts the bandwidth, or something;
- connect another phone of your friend, preferably with the same phone model to the same WiFi access point, to understand if the issue is connected to specific phone, or to specific access point.
- try to reboot WiFI router, and the Iphone, to see if this will help as well, it could be some temporary hardware/software glitch.
- if your WiFi router has several WiFi bandwidths: 5GHz and standard - try switching to one mode, without 5GHz, sometimes it helps, as phone is shifting between them and might loose the connection.

Hope this helps you to troubleshoot!

Comment: Thanks! To specify, to my knowledge the other two iPhone users in the house do not experience the same problem. My wifi is usually 2-3 bars, and works well on all sites and apps other than YouTube.

Comment: Also, sometimes it goes for a long time without cutting out, and other times cuts out every five minutes.

Comment: @Mathime, try to do these actions one by one, and see if it helps. Feel free to upvote the answer if found useful. Please, make some feedback if solved.

Comment: And in response to rebooting the iPhone: as I said I have experienced this issue for a long time, and my iPhone (and almost certainly router) has been rebooted several times since then.